# Ninject DI - Placement of binding in an MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject

I have a very layered MVC3 application (seperate projects for the domain, services, web, infrastructure, etc.)

I understand the concept of controller constructor injection, which MVC3 and Ninject work so kindly together.  But what about injection for layers separate from the web layer?

For example, I have a service that relies on a Repository interface.  The service is called from the controller, and the service itself will be injected properly by the constructor injection, but what about the repository?  How do I inject that?

```
public class MyService
{
  protected virtual IPersonRepository PersonRepository {get; set;}

  public virtual void UseRepository()
  {
    PersonRepository.FindEveryoneInTheWorldButDontReturnThem();
  }
}
```

Where/how do I [n]inject the repository in the above example?

Ninject 3.0
Ninject.Web.MVC 3.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the repository via constructor injection, and your IoC container (Ninject) will take care of dependency chains (i.e. when you inject MyService as a dependency, any of its dependencies will also be resolved by the container, and their dependencies and so on)

```
public MyService(IPersonRepository personRepository)
{
    this.PersonRepository = personRepository;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there also a [Inject] attribute that you can use?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I have a dependency in my repository that must also be resolved.  However, requiring that all repositories use constructor injection for dependencies seems a little un-needed.

Comment: Have a read of https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns. "If no constructors have an [Inject] attribute, Ninject will select the one with the most parameters that Ninject understands how to resolve. If no constructors are defined, Ninject will select the default parameterless constructor (assuming there is one)."

Comment: If they are required dependencies then it's perfectly reasonable that they would be injected via the constructor.